# How to manage line breaks when the line contains `makebox`?

Tags: boxes, exam

If I write fill-in-the-blank questions in the `exam` class, like this:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question [3] The protagonist, originally from \makebox[2in]{\dotfill}, has to travel up the \makebox[2in]{\dotfill} River to retrieve \makebox[2in]{\dotfill}.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The lines don't break properly, but run all the way to the edge of the page, like this:

[image]

I can put in `\\` to force a line break, which does produce an acceptable result:

[image]

But this seems clunky. Is there a more elegant way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may as well let the dots expand rather than white space, and then line breaking is a lot easier

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\newcommand\mydotfill[1]{{\def\hfill{\hskip #1 plus 1fill\relax}\nolinebreak\dotfill}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question [3] The protagonist, originally from \mydotfill{2in}, has to travel up the \mydotfill{2in} River to retrieve \mydotfill{2in}.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So if I'm reading that right, you ease line breaks by making dotfills of _approximately_ 2 in.? Nice.

Comment: @crmdgn "at least" rather than "approximately" but yes.